# How to create a flink producer job without consumer

Tags: java-8, apache-flink

I have created a `Flink` application/job using flink consumer and producer concepts.

Now I have one more requirement like I need to create a `Producer` application which publishes data to a `topic` which is consumed above `Flink` Application. I created this `Producer` application using `KafkaProducer` & it is working as expected. But I also need to run this `Producer` Application as `Flink` Job. I did searching in google, I am unable to find details to create a `Flink` Application only with Producer.

Comment: You can use an empty source, which terminates only when cancelled. But note that without data flowing through the workflow, your operator(s) that are generating data won't get called. As David noted, more details on how you're generating data would help.

Answer (score 0):

Every Flink job needs to have at least one source and one sink. However it is you plan to come up with the data that will be written to the producer, use one of the available sources to read or generate it, or implement your own.

Where will the data come from?

Comment: Then you should be able to either use env.readfile, or implement a custom source.

Comment: I tried with env.readfile it is not working for me, previously I tried to read files from IBM-COS using flink which was failed due to lot of issues